# What is the mechanism to incorporate send and download postman option from within Newman call

Tags: newman

What is the mechanism to incorporate send and download postman option from within Newman call?

Output of my REST call is file (image/binary). On running with Newman I don't see the output. Is there any way to save the contents in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of now newman do not have this feature. but you can have a workaround where you can read the output stream and write it into the file at desired location .
attaching sample code :

```
    var i = 0,
    fs = require('fs'),
    newman = require('newman'); // ensure that you have run "npm i newman" in the same directory as this file

newman.run({
  // run options go here
}, function (err, summary) {
  // handle collection run err, process the run summary here
}).on('request', function (err, execution) { // This is triggered when a response has been recieved
   if (err) { return console.error(err); }

   fs.writeFile(`response${i++}.txt`, execution.response.stream, function (error) {
      if (error) { console.error(error); }
   });
});
```